# failed connection to graph.facebook port 443 during login with facebook application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I start to developing an app with login page, and I try to use "facebook login", but I got the following error:

> Facebook SDK returned an error: Failed to connect to graph.facebook.com port 443: Connection refused

I created the app with PHP using code from github.

someone can help me please?

Comment: Contact your ISP or server provider and ask them

Comment: Please add a lot more detail about what you have tried and include your reproduction code.

Comment: ok. i use this code:  https://github.com/sohaibilyas/facebook-php-sdk-v5/blob/master/login-on-website-get-basic-info.php  . for now I only want to login to facebook, but I get the aforementioned error. thank you for your help !!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the code used. You have some kind of network/connectivity issue. As already said: Go ask your server admin to look into it.